# Create multiple matrices from 2 bigger ones in R

Tags: r

I have 2 matrices, A (1000x21) and B (1000x7). Matrix A has individuals(=1000) in the rows and their consumption in 21 days at the columns. Matrix B has the **SAME** individuals(=1000) in the rows and some weights for each day of the week(=7) in the columns.

What I would like to have in the end is 1000 (with the dimension of 2x21) matrices  (one for each individual), lets call them $X_{i}$. In the first row of each $X_{i}$ I would like to have the consumption of the individual $i$ each of the 21 days (this will come from matrix A), and at the second row of the $X_{i}$ I would like to have the respective weight of that day (this will come from matrix B).

So matrix A looks like $[cons_{1,1} \ cons_{1,2} \ ... \ cons_{1,21} \\
                        \ cons_{2,1} \ cons_{2,2} \ ... \ cons_{2,21} \\
                                     . \\
                        . \\
                         . \\
                       \ cons_{1000,1} \ cons_{1000,2} \ ... \ cons_{1000,21}] $

Matrix B looks like $[weight_{1,1} \ weight_{1,2} \ ... \ weight_{1,7} \\ \ weight_{2,1} \ weight_{2,2} \ ... \ weight_{2,7} \\ . \\ . \\ . \\ \ weight_{1000,1} \ weight_{1000,2} \ ... \ weight_{1000,7}]$

And I would like the matrix $X_{i}$ to be like $[cons_{i,1} \ cons_{i,2} \ ... \ cons_{i,21} \\ \ weight_{i,1} \ weight_{i,2} \ ... weight_{i,k}]$

Any ideas how to do this in R in a loop ?

Comment: Do you want to have 1000 separate matrix objects or have them in a list?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will extract the rows from matrix **A** and **B**.

```
matrix(c(A[x,],rep(B[x,],times=3)),nrow=2,byrow=T)
```

If you want to get them into a list (recommend)

```
single<-lapply(c(1:1000), function(x) matrix(c(A[x,],rep(B[x,],times=3)),nrow=2,byrow=T))
```

To put them all in diagonal matrix with *adiag* from **magic** package

```
d<-adiag(single[[1]])

for(i in 2:1000){
  d<-adiag(d,single[[i]])
}
```

I could make it work without the loop (anyone any suggestions?)

Comment: Hi Jan and thank you for the answer. In the second command with the lapply, the function will take as argument the vector c(1:0000) right ? 

Moreover, after running this command single will be a list containing the 1000 matrices. So, if I need to extract lets say the first matrix, I will have to use single[[1]] ? (I am sorry I am not very familiar with lists)

Lastly, do you know how this could be done with matrices ? My idea would be to create the 1000 matrices and then put them all in the diagonal of a huge matrix using the command "adiag". What do you think ?

Comment: Also now 21 **is** divided by 7. Your way in this case is really smart. But what if A had 20 rows ?

Comment: Yes, the access to the elements is exactly as you say. You probably could put them in one large matrix. I will have a look at it, never done it myself. And regarding the last comment, you mean if A had 20 columns? It would be up to you to make sure when you create the matrix, it has correct size. So if you had 41 elements, R would fill the missing element with the first element again - try `matrix(c(1:41), nrow=2)`

Comment: No I mean, that now you put in the first row the 21 column-elements of A and in the second row you put  the 7 column-elements of B times 3 (so 3x7=21). that way the number of elements of each row match. But what if A had 20 columns ? Then you would need to put 2 times the column-elements of B and then put the rest 6 (so 2x7+6=20). Right ? Then I guess it should be done like matrix(c(A[x,],rep(B[x,],times=2),B[x,1:6]),...). Correct ?

Comment: yh that should work :) you can for example make a working example have two simple 3x3 matrices A and B and play around with the ideas and see what works. That will teach you the best  (also I was checking on toy example if the code works)...regarding the adiag - it will make 42 x 21000 matrix, that is 6.7Mb worth of data..what you gonna do with it? :D

Comment: Actually it would be 2000x21000 matrix :P. I could burn my laptop :P. Thank you :)

Comment: Yh you right, I found solution, will edit my answer.

Comment: One last question. If I want to access the (3,2) element from the first matrix in the "single" list, how should I do it ? Or if I want to access the 2nd column of the first matrix in the "single" list, how should I do it ?

Comment: If you go single[[1]] it subsets the whole thing there and then behaves as usual matrix. So single[[1]][3,2] will return element in the first matrix, 3rd row, 2nd column. single[[1]][,2] returns second column :)